# Pass json array from PHP to JS

Tags: php, jquery, json

I need to send a json array from a php script to Javascript.

```html
 <?php
//controllo se sono presenti i parametri
if(isset($_GET['ID_utente']) && isset($_GET['Longitudine']) && isset($_GET['Latitudine']))
{
//Recupero il valore dei parametri
$ID_utente = $_GET['ID_utente'];
$Longitudine = $_GET['Longitudine'];
$Latitudine = $_GET['Latitudine'];
}

//eseguo la connessione al database sul server locale
//inserendo nome utente e password
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'realegr', 'rabredugbo19');
 
//gestione degli errori
// if (!$conn) {die('Impossibile connettersi: ' . mysql_error());}
 
//seleziono il databse
mysql_select_db("my_realegr") or die( "Impossibile selezionare il database.");
 
//creo una stringa sql di inserimento con i valori
//recuperati dall'url
$sql = "INSERT INTO `my_realegr`.`DatiSinistro`
(
`ID_sinistro` ,
`Tempo_Server` ,
`Tempo_Locale` ,
`ID_utente`,
`Longitudine`,
`Latitudine`
)
VALUES
(
NULL , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , NULL , '" . $ID_utente . "', '" . $Longitudine . "', '" . $Latitudine . "')
";

$q = "SELECT Longitudine, Latitudine FROM DatiSinistro ORDER by ID_sinistro 
DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($q, $conn);

    if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         echo json_encode([
           'status' => true,
           'latitude' => $row['Latitudine'],
           'longitude' => $row['Longitudine'],
         ]);
    }




 
//gestione degli errori
if(! $result ){die('Impossibile eseguire la query: ' . mysql_error());}
 
//chiudo la connessione al db
mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   
   

        <script async defer 
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBkEtPH07_xBVh8dWBzCQYtWimkOUnPGMQ&callback=initMap"></script>
    
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
        
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>    
    
    <script>
function initMap(){
  


     var $request = $.get('http://realegr.altervista.org/ProvaReale1.php');
     $request.done( function(data) {
     alert(data);
          var pasedData = JSON.parse(data);
          alert(pasedData.latitude);
 
          
     var uluru = {lat: pasedData.latitude, lng:pasedData.longitude};
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 4,
              center: uluru
                                                                   });
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: uluru,
              map: map
                                          });
              
})
}
</script>
    
    

  </body>
</html>
```

Output of php script:[image]

When I load Maps,alert(data) shows me : {"status":true,"latitude":"45.062583","longitude":"7.662160"}

So PHP script seems work well and besides Javascript receives JSON array
With "var pasedData = JSON.parse(data); " do I obtain an array parsed??
When I try to show the content with alert(pasedData[0]) it shows me "undefined".What's wrong?

Comment: use pasedData.status, pasedData.latitude and pasedData.longitude

Comment: hi dear 
your out put not in `JSON` array `{"status":true,"latitude":"45.062583","longitude":"7.662160"}`
if your output like this
`[{"status":true,"latitude":"45.062583","longitude":"7.662160"}]` then you  can use like this pasedData[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pasedData.status`, `pasedData.latitude` and `pasedData.longitude`

**UPDATED**

Please use this code

```
<script>
function initMap(){
  //
}
</script>
```

and place your code of `initMap` inside this function.

**UPDATE 2**

Please use this code

```
var pasedData = JSON.parse(data);
var longi = parseFloat(pasedData.longitude);
var lati = parseFloat(pasedData.latitude);
var uluru = {lat: lati, lng:longi};
```

Comment: Thank you.But now in console I have a new error:                                       

fc {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new fc (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…_xBVh8dWBzCQYtWimkOUnPGMQ&callback=initMap:136:68"}

   any hint??
(I have changed the script)

Comment: Do you have a function initMap() in your script tag? It is javascript function.

Comment: I updated the script (If I understood what u meant ).    
   Now it gives me these errors:    InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number;       InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Comment: Can you please update your code in your question so that I can see?

Comment: Already done. Anyway it's strange because the values are already parsed :S

Comment: @Nick9214 Please see "UPDATE 2"

Comment: You need to typecast these.

Comment: Oh no..there is an error in query part...and it would be an OT for this post,do you mind if I contact you?I think it's not a big deal,but I am going crazy...i need this for a project,pls

Comment: Yes sure you can contact me at ali.zia.1991@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Access with `.` operator in place of trying it like array index.
It will Work. Can try below example in browser console.

```
var data = '{"status":true,"latitude":"45.062583","longitude":"7.662160"}';
var t = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(t.status);
```